# Javadoc fails on Oracle JDK but doesn't on OpenJDK

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a simple project with
src/main/java/test/Test.java

```
package test;
/**
 * Class java doc
 */ 
public class Test
{
    /**
     * Wrong java doc
     *
     * @param test
     * @return 
     */
    public int aMethod(int param){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
      <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When building on Linux with oracle-jdk8 (161) it fails because of the incorrect javadoc

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:3.0.0:jar (attach-javadocs) on project test: MavenReportException: Error while generating Javadoc: 
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - /home/D070061/SAPDevelop/test/src/main/java/test/Test.java:10: error: @param name not found
[ERROR]      * @param test
```

When doing the same with open-jdk8 (v171) the build  is successful

I switch the java with `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Does anybody know why it doesn't fail on OpenJDK? Is it a bug or is there some special parameters needed?

Comment: The documentation is not correct it should be @param param my description for the param.

Comment: Yes I know that the documentation is not correct. I'll reformulate the question. Why doesn't it fail on OpenJDK?

Comment: What happens if you build on the same version numbers?  Both on v161 or both on v171?

Comment: As there is now 161 openJdk I tried it with 162 with the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that [Debian patches javadoc to disable doclint by default](https://github.com/Debian/openjdk-8/blob/master/debian/patches/disable-doclint-by-default.patch), as presumably do some derived and other distributions.

The Maven Javadoc plugin added a `<doclint>` configuration item in 3.0.0, so for that version and later you should be able to re-enable doclint by specifying e.g.:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <doclint>all</doclint>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling DocLint in the Maven configuration? You can do this easily by adding -Xdoclint:none to the global properties in your pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
      <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
  </properties>
  <build>
      <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: My goal is not to deactivate doclint for JavaDoc generation but to find a way to generate syntactically correct JavaDoc. The generation has to fail if  the doc linter  finds some problem. In my Example openjdk seems to omit doclint at all. The question is why